# Using CSS to make sure my Logo is always X ammount of distance away from border

Tags: css, layout

I'm trying to make sure my web application is always centered on the screen regardless of screen resolution. I've tried:

```
.Logo
{
    Top:15px;
    Left:50%;   
}
```

But it's not doing anything really. Any help, wise CSS-Gurus?

Comment: Your question title and your question body don't match :S

Comment: How so? :S I'm asking how to make this Logo appear X amount of distance. I can't set a fixed Pixel number because of different resolutions.

Comment: Centering means a variable length from the top according to the screen size, whereas the title makes it seem like what you need is just a `position:absolute;`, what you needed is to center an element on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [vertical alignment,](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html) you need something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#outer {height: 400px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;}
#outer[id] {display: table; position: static;}

#middle {position: absolute; top: 50%;} /* for explorer only*/
#middle[id] {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 100%;}

#inner {position: relative; top: -50%} /* for explorer only */
/* optional: #inner[id] {position: static;} */
</style>
```

For [horizontal alignment](http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/center-div-block.shtml) you need something like this

```
body{text-align:center;}/*fix for ie*/
body *{text-align:left;}
#outer {
  width: 700px ;
  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
}
```

On this `html`:

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="middle">
    <div id="inner">
      any text
      any height
      any content, for example generated from DB
      everything is vertically centered
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you must use `position:absolute;` for this to work

Comment: can we please see a testcase of your page?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.Logo {
     margin: auto;
     width: 600px; /* or other value */
}
```

if .Logo is a block level element it should work.

Comment: My DIV is only surrounding an img tag for testing purposes. Your code isn't changing anything in the layout. :( I'm so lost! :P

Answer (score 0):

```
.Logo
{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Works in IE6.  I can't remember about Firefox as it's such a long time since I did any web development (sigh!).

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
.logo
{
    display:block;
    margin:15px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.ff {padding-left:50%; padding-top:50%}